# Compressing a list of files contain spaces in their file-names

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I’ve been trying to compress a set of files contain spaces in thier file-names using a bash file. The bash file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -cPf 'myconfigs.tar' `cat myconfigs.list`
```

The content of myconfigs.list file is:

```
/home/anas/.config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks
/home/anas/.config/chromium/Default/Login Data
/home/anas/.config/chromium/Default/Login Data-journal
```

The problem is that files contain spaces in their file-names don’t be included in the result TAR archive.
I tried '', "", %20... but didn’t work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @galaxy, @anubhava: BTW, I'm trying to replace `/home/anas/` with `~/` but I failed, any solution please?

Answer (score 4):

Anas,

I think you need to use:

```
tar -cPf myconfigs.tar -T myconfigs.list
```

instead of your "cat" .  cat should work too if you properly escape the filenames inside, but -T is better.

**UPDATED** (to address your question in question's comments):
I cannot comment in your question (don't have enough reputation), so I decided to improve my answer instead.

The tilde (~) expansion is a shell thing, tar does not support it.  However, to achieve what you want to achieve, you can use the following trick:

- use relative paths in your myconfigs.list file (relative to the home directory):

```
    .config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks
    .config/chromium/Default/Login Data
    .config/chromium/Default/Login Data-journal
```

- run tar in such way that it changes directory to your home on startup:

```
    tar -cPf myconfigs.tar -C ~/ -T myconfigs.list
```

OK, I went ahead and created a sample session illustrating it:

```
root@web:~ # useradd -m galaxy
root@web:~ # su - galaxy
galaxy@web:~ $ mkdir -p {1,2}/{3,4}/{5,6,7}
galaxy@web:~ $ find . -xdev -type d -exec touch '{}/file.txt' \;
galaxy@web:~ $ cat << EOF > include.lst
> 1/3
> 1/4/5/file.txt
> 1/4/7
> 2/file.txt
> EOF
galaxy@web:~ $ cd 2/3/6
galaxy@web:~/2/3/6 $ tar cjSpf ~/sample.tar.bz2 -C ~/ -T ~/include.lst
galaxy@web:~/2/3/6 $ cd
galaxy@web:~ $ tar tjvf sample.tar.bz2
drwx------ galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/3/
-rw------- galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/3/file.txt
drwx------ galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/3/7/
-rw------- galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/3/7/file.txt
drwx------ galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/3/6/
-rw------- galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/3/6/file.txt
drwx------ galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/3/5/
-rw------- galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/3/5/file.txt
-rw------- galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/4/5/file.txt
drwx------ galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/4/7/
-rw------- galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 1/4/7/file.txt
-rw------- galaxy/galaxy     0 2014-02-19 04:10 2/file.txt
galaxy@web:~ $
```

This *should* give you a start :)

Comment: Well, it should.  Did you receive any error messages? Check your tar documentation for -T and -C options.  Some tar's allow you to incorporate -C into the file you are using with -T . Oh, and what user you are running this command under?  If it's not 'anas' then you need to use '~anas/' instead of '~/'.

Comment: As a result I'm receiving an empty `myconfigs.tar` file.
The point is: I want to back-up _Current-user_'s files regardless of what the user's name is; simply the current user (`~/`).
btw, I'm using tar v1.26.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use cat's output like that otherwise space is considered a delimiter and a separete argument to the `tar` command.

You can use [`-T` tar option](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/files.html):

```
tar -cPv -T myconfigs.list -f myconfigs.tar
```